# Mathematically correct expressions for basic operations

Tags: grammar, terminology, mathematics

There are several similar questions out there, but there is no systematic approach to the problem.  So I will try to put all four operations together:

c = a + b

c = a * b

c = a - b

c = a / b

What are **mathematically** (**not** everyday speaking) correct expressions for these four operations?

Now, the first two are more-or-less straightforward:

c is the **sum of** a **and** b

c is the **product of** a **and** b

Things become ambiguous for the third expression:

c is the **difference of** a **and** b

c is the **difference between** a **and** b

The fourth expression is even more ambiguous

c is the **quotient of** a **and** b

c is the **ratio of** a **and** b

c is the **ratio between** a **and** b

Which of those would be most appropriate for use in mathematics and physics?

Comment: They'd all need definite articles, for a start. "c is _the_ sum of a and b"...

Comment: @kaipmdh Thanks, corrected.

Comment: If c = a - b, c is not necessarily the difference between a and b. This presupposes a is not less than b. d = |a - b| is the difference between a and b. Generally, one has to say c is a take b.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with "c is the quotient of a and b". Could you cite some evidence that it is ambiguous?

Comment: What are the 'everyday speaking' versions of these? The only -alternate- "c equals a plus b" which sounds much more mathematical.

Comment: @rajah9 It is ambiguous which expression to use.  Or maybe not, if you are a mathematician and a native English speaker.

Comment: @Pygmalion Also, ambiguity is about having multiple meanings, not having legitimate alternatives for the same meaning.

Comment: Contra @EdwinAshworth, I have never seen "a take b" in any math or physics paper or textbook. The textbook definitions of c, a, and b are *difference*, *subtrahend*, and *minuend*, regardless of their magnitudes.

Comment: @Mitch There are certainly many expressions in everyday use, probably not all are mathematically correct.  Example: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265973/ratio-expressions-which-are-correct

Comment: what are the multiple meanings, causing an ambiguity? Take a look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94290/alternative-to-minuend-and-subtrahend. minuend − subtrahend = difference. I see neither multiple meanings nor ambiguity either "c is the difference of a and b" or "c is the difference between a and b." And let me qualify: I am an American English speaker who reads math and math finance papers.

Comment: @rajah9 Well maybe both are correct, at least auspicious99 thinks so.  I suppose I wouldn't ask if I knew the answer.  Let me qualify: English as a second or even third language, which I started learning at age of 12.

Comment: @rajah9 The textbooks you have seen are flawed, or we are missing a non-negative codomain restriction. Mod[a-b] is the difference if no restrictions have been specified. // Also, in higher maths, a specifying definition for 'product' is the result of _any_ binary operation. a + b, a - b ... a M b (where M is 'take the mean), a * b.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you meant Abs(a-b), not mod(a-b). // I have not heard of 'product' being the result of any binary operation besides multiplication. Could you provide a reference? // I have not read *a take b* in any paper. Could you provide a reference? // In my 5th grade class, I remember Mrs. Furgeson saying you couldn't subtract a larger number from a smaller one. She asserted, "You can't subtract 5 from 3!" "Sure you can," I replied. "Negative 2." Flustered, she moved on to the next topic.

Comment: @rajah9 [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/absolute_value). // product (general): [Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Operation/Binary_Operation/Product) // trivially, [Examples in Algebra](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0rVjAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=%22a+take+b%22&source=bl&ots=ye8B0nyPKU&sig=ACfU3U3RTP-0DMth0U49Wc5QimQ0Pl12Ww&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22a%20take%20b%22&f=false) // I assume the next topic wasn't quaternions.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a - b

> c is the **difference of** a **and** b (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_two_squares) for an example)

> c is the **difference between** a **and** b (see [math is fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/difference.html) for an example)

Both are acceptable, and both mean a - b, but "difference between" is more common than "difference of".

As for a/b

> c is the quotient of a and b

is correct.

According to [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/quotient), a quotient is:

> 1 *Mathematics*
>
> A result obtained by dividing one quantity by another.

whereas [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ratio) also defines ratio as:

> The quantitative relation between two amounts showing the number of times one value contains or is contained within the other.

Besides, a ratio is typically represented with ":" rather than "/". If you did have a:b, you would write

> c is the **ratio of** a **to** b (see [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/when-describing-a-ratio-should-between-or-of-be-used) for example)

"ratio" should be used with "to".

Comment: Thanks.  Could you please also write which of ratio expressions is correct (for quantitative relation between two amounts)?

Comment: Actually, neither of them is correct. I've added the ratio expression to my answer.

Comment: @Pygmalion Sometimes people write things like 'pi = "ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter"', where it should actually be 'pi:1 = "ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter"', to be consistent.

Comment: @Pygmalion Yes, both "quotient of a *and* b" and "quotient of a *by* b" can be found in use in various texts.

Comment: I finally figured out.  According to standard ISO 80000, ratio is quotient which dimension is 1.  It is explicitly written so.

Comment: I actually like quotient of ... and, because then it is consistent for all four operations, but standard explicitly specifies `A quantity defined as A/B is called ‘quotient of A by B’ or ‘A per B’, but not ‘A per unit B’.`

Answer (score 0):

Please note the use of the definite article.

> Things become ambiguous for the third expression

No, they do not.

<s>c is **the** difference of a and b</s>

c is **the** difference **between** a and b

> The fourth expression is even more ambiguous

No – a quotient is an absolute. It is the result of dividing a by b.

c is **the** quotient of a and b (In basic terms, this means "The answer to a/b is c.")

1695   W. Alingham Geometry Epitomiz'd 73   If..I divide 54 by 3 the quotient is 18.

A **ratio** is without units and is a comparison of relative quantities or metrics within a given sample, so as to provide a universal conversion factor, or as the OED says

> **3. a. The relation between two magnitudes in respect of quantity, esp. as determined by the number of times that one contains the other … .Usually expressed in terms of the smallest integers between which the same relationship hold. Thus 20 and 100 are in described as in the ratio 1 to 5, rather than 2 to 10 or 4 to 20.**

“In this sample the ratio of gold to rock is three parts per thousand.” This is written “In this sample the ratio of gold **to** rock is 3:1000.”

"The price for 4 metres is £20. The ratio of the length to the price is 1 to 5, and so 20 metres will cost £100."

<s>c is **the** ratio of a and b</s>

<s>c is **the** ratio between a and b</s>

Comment: So essentially, everyone have **of** except for **difference**.

Answer (score -1):

You need a word change:

*C is equal to the difference of b FROM a.*

*C is the quotient of a OVER b.*